# How to disable loader / spinner after page load with Bootstrap 4?

Tags: html, css, beautifulsoup

I‘ve created a page with a data table with Bootstrap 4. In some cases the table is very large and the data retrieval takes a few seconds. Therefore I‘ve added a spinner / loader which shows that the page is still loading. However, the spinner does not stop as expected when the page is completely loaded and I can't find a note in the documentation how to implement this. Am I using the "div" element incorrectly or do I need JavaScript? - Unfortunately I have 0% knowledge of JavaScript. Or is this a browser/OS specific issue? (I'm using Firefox / Linux).

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, Table!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    
    <div class="container">
    
      <div class="pt-3">
    <span class="h1 mr-3">Large Table</span>

      <div class="spinner-border text-primary" role="status">
  <span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>
</div>
      </div>
    
    
    <div class="table-responsive pt-3">
 
        <table class="table table-hover">
  <thead class="thead-dark">
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Column 1</th>
      <th scope="col">Column 2</th>
      <th scope="col">Column 3</th>
      <th scope="col">Column 4</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">Name 1</th>
      <td>Data</td>
      <td>Data</td>
      <td>Data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">Name 2</th>
      <td>Data</td>
      <td>Data</td>
      <td>Data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">Name 3</th>
      <td>Data</td>
      <td>Data</td>
      <td>Data</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>    
</div>
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
    
</html>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   // executes when HTML-Document is loaded and DOM is ready
 });
```

OR

```
 $(window).load(function() {
   // executes when complete page is fully loaded, including all frames, objects and images
});
```

or if you want to hide loader after checking the table is present in DOM or not, then you can check if the table is presnt or not by its tag or selctor length.

Something like this.

```
var yourElement= document.getElementById("yourElement");
if(yourElement){
   // Element exists
}
```

By jQuery

```
if ($( "#yourElement").length) {
   // element exists
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('.spinner-border').hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, Table!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    
    <div class="container">
    
      <div class="pt-3">
    <span class="h1 mr-3">Large Table</span>

      <div class="spinner-border text-primary" role="status">
  <span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>
</div>
      </div>
    
    
    <div class="table-responsive pt-3">
 
        <table class="table table-hover">
  <thead class="thead-dark">
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Column 1</th>
      <th scope="col">Column 2</th>
      <th scope="col">Column 3</th>
      <th scope="col">Column 4</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">Name 1</th>
      <td>Data</td>
      <td>Data</td>
      <td>Data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">Name 2</th>
      <td>Data</td>
      <td>Data</td>
      <td>Data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">Name 3</th>
      <td>Data</td>
      <td>Data</td>
      <td>Data</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>    
</div>
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
    
</html>
```

Comment: @peter if this helped you, don't forget to mark it as the right answer.

Comment: thank you for reminder. Yes, `$(document).ready(function() {
      $('.spinner-border').hide();
});` was very helpful for me. Best Regards.